# ReactWrapper::state() can only be called on class components Unit Testing Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

Writing unit testing in react using jest and enzyme. While checking with a component state , it throws an error "ReactWrapper::state() can only be called on class components ".

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import expect from 'expect';
import CustomerAdd from '../CustomerAdd'
import MUITheme from '../../../../Utilities/MUITheme';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

describe('<CustomerAdd />', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
        <ThemeProvider theme={MUITheme}>
          <CustomerAdd {...mockProps}></CustomerAdd>
        </ThemeProvider>
        );
        test('something', () => {
            expect(wrapper.find(CustomerAdd).state('addNewOnSubmit')).toEqual(true);
        });
});
```

In the above code CustomerAdd Component is class component.I don't what wrong with my code. Can any one help me out of this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hard to say for sure. check your import/export. I mean default export can be a wrapper around class-based component while you need to use named export. PS anyway, you better not asserting against `state()`, tests become fragile.

Comment: i think issue when using the functional component used as wrapper in class based component . any solution for this ?

Comment: how is it declared?

Comment: the ThemeProvider is material ui ThemeProvider component . it's a functional component. If i remove this and corresponding dependencies removed from CustomerAdd . It's working fine . But i need CustomerAdd with ThemeProvider

Comment: how does default export for `'../CustomerAdd'` look like?

Comment: export default withStyles(styles)(CustomerAdd);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So your default export

```
export default withStyles(styles)(CustomerAdd);
```

exports functional(HOC) wrapper about your class-based component. And it does not matter if name of class and import in

```
import CustomerAdd from '../CustomerAdd'
```

are equal. Your test imports wrapped version and after calling `.find(CustomerAdd)` returns that HOC not your class. And you're unable to work with instance.

#### Short time solution: export class directly as named export.

```
export class CustomerAdd extends React.Component{
  ...
}

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomerAdd);
```

Use named import in your tests:

```
import { CustomerAdd } from '../CusomerAdd';
```

#### Quick'n'dirty solution: use [`.dive`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) to access your underlying class-based component:

```
expect(wrapper.find(CustomerAdd).dive().state('addNewOnSubmit')).toEqual(true);
```

It's rather antipattern since if you add any additional HOC in your default export you will need to monkey-patch all related tests with adding appropriate amount of `.dive().dive()....dive()` calls.

#### Long-term solution: avoid testing state, it's implementation details.

Instead focus on validating what's been rendered. Then you are safe in case of lot of different refactoring technics like replacing class with functional component, renaming state/instance members, lifting state up, connecting component to Redux etc.

Comment: expect(wrapper.find('CustomerAdd').state('addNewOnSubmit')).toEqual(true); this  worked for me :)

Comment: fine, but that's a most tricky way since you're relying on `displayName` implicitly set by React itself based on class' name. say if you replace class with  functional component like `const CustomerAdd = function ... ` approach with named import will still work while `find('CustomerAdd')` will break.

Comment: @skyboyer "Long-term solution: avoid testing state, it's implementation details" - if i want test a render based on a state change. then i would do that ?

Comment: @Liron, your state achievable through sequence of events stimulated and mocking what external sources(`fetch`, `Math.random` etc) return. So mock and simulate.