# Testing a button's state with a withRouter-wrapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have a component that is currently wrapped with withRouter (e.g. I use `export default withRouter(myComponent)`) since I need am using `history.push` for one of my links within the component. I am writing a test in Enzyme that tests whether a button in that component changes its state to true/false when the user clicks it. The test is failing with the error that it cannot read the property of isExpanded of null. This is what I have for my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { mount, configure } from 'enzyme';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import myComponent from './myComponent';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

 describe('Successful flows', () => {
   test('button changes state when clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter><myComponent /></MemoryRouter>);
    const moreBtn = wrapper.find('.seeMoreButton').at(0);
    moreBtn.simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.state().isExpanded).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

I have found that before I used withRouter and just had `const wrapper = mount(<myComponent />);` in my test, the test passed. I am fairly new to routing and I feel like there's something I'm missing here so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the state of the wrong component, the result of `mount` will be `MemoryRouter`, not `myComponent`.

After you mount the component, you'll need to find `myComponent` and verify its state instead

```
test('button changes state when clicked', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter><myComponent /></MemoryRouter>);
  const comp = wrapper.find(myComponent);
  const moreBtn = comp.find('.seeMoreButton').at(0);
  moreBtn.simulate('click');
  expect(comp.state().isExpanded).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: When I do that I get the error “ReactWrapper::state() can only be called on class components”

Comment: @PythonSOS that's an issue related to testing HOCs, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58429807/reactwrapperstate-can-only-be-called-on-class-components-unit-testing-jest-a).